# Input impedance of input pin from Xilinx CoolRunner II CPLD

Tags: xilinx, programmable-logic

[image]

Is the effective resistance mentioned in the image the input resistance for the CPLD pins? I am using Vccio at 3.3 V.

(Image is from Xilinx CPLD IO guide application note).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is the impedance of the circuitry that implements a pull-up or keeper. The **input** impedance will typically be much larger, and is usually specified as a maximum input **current** over some range of voltages.

Comment: thank you for answering , i can't find any mentioning on input current at the datasheet .Can i ask you something more ?

Comment: Look for a table of "DC Electrical Characteristics" in the device datasheet. Xilinx calls this parameter "Input Leakage Current".